# Is it useful to create reusable IntStreams? If yes, how?

Tags: java, stream

I am wondering, whether it makes sense to create a reusable IntStream for the following problem and how to do so.

Basically, I need to loop over an int[] of numbers to be detected and and count the frequency of these numbers in another int[].

If I had an IntStream-Supplier, it was reusable in some loop. So, I am looking for something like

```java
int[] intsToBeDectected = new int[]{1,2,3}
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3}
Supplier<IntStream> supplier = IntStream.of(numbers); // ERROR
for (int i : intsToBeDetected){
   int freq = (int) supplier.get().filter(n -> n=i).count();
}
```

From object streams in java, I know something like this:

```java
Supplier<Stream<Object>> supplier = () -> Arrays.stream(objects)
```

This stream of objects is reusable like:

```java
supplier.get().filter()...
```

However, I somehow fail to transfer this idea to IntStreams - It's not compiling in the line commented with ERROR.

Does it make sense to transfer this concept? If yes, how to do so?

Comment: And what's the error message ? The way I see it, IntStream.of returns IntStream and you're trying to make it into Supplier of IntStream.

Comment: What are you going to achieve here? Which frequency do you need to find?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
Supplier<IntStream> supplier = IntStream.of(numbers); // ERROR
```

with

```
Supplier<IntStream> supplier = () -> IntStream.of(numbers);
```